# Python cannot find a usbtmc device

Tags: python, usb, visa

I'm trying to communicate with a hardware device I have (Yokogawa GS200 DC source).
I am using Anaconda\Spyder my development environment.
I am using Win10 and a 64bit system.
The device has a driver (the 64bit version) and is recognized by my PC (shown in the device manager.

when I use:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
lst = rm.list_resources('?*')
print(lst)
```

It does not return the GS200 device.

If I try to open the device by sepcifying the adress:

```
my_instrument = rm.open_resource("USB0::0x0B21::0x0039::91U118228::INSTR")
```

I get:

```
VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.
```

I tried this code (seen answered elsewhere):

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
list = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
connected = []
for element in list:
    connected.append(element.device)
print("Connected COM ports: " + str(connected))
```

which returns:

```
Connected COM ports: []
```

Moreover, I have reinstalled the driver. disconnected and reconnected, restarted my PC and nothing changed the status.

I have tried using this code as well:

```
import visa
rmNI = visa.ResourceManager(r'C:\Windows\System32\visa32.dll')
rmNI.list_resources()
print(rmNI.list_resources())
```

and the device still is not detected.

Would love to hear any suggestion!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`PyVisa` is only the frontend, you have to install a backend VISA library i.e. NI-VISA

> PyVISA is a frontend to the VISA library. It runs on Python 2.6+ and 3.2+.
>
> **NI Backend**
>
> In order for PyVISA to work, you need to have a suitable backend.
>   PyVISA includes a backend that wraps the National Instruments’s VISA
>   library. However, you need to download and install the library
>   yourself (See NI-VISA Installation). There are multiple VISA
>   implementations from different vendors. PyVISA is tested only against
>   National Instruments’s VISA.

source:  https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting.html

follow the steps in **https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html**

also see this : https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/i-can-t-communicate-with-Yokogawa-GS200-through-USB-in-Labview/td-p/1401104

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I uave installed pyVisa, but im not sure what is the NI backend and if it is configured correctly. To which folder the path should be linked?